# Keep Picklist values in a flow when redirecting

Tags: visual-workflow, picklist, customization, default-value, flow-builder

I have a flow to create a lead record. I have several fields, some of them are picklists where i have 2 choices, one choice for --None--, and another choice with the values of this field. For example, like the picture below:

[image]

In my flow, the steps are the following:

1. Screen -> New Lead (provides all the necessary fields to the user in order to fill them in)
2. Assignment -> Assign all the values inserted by the user to a Lead Record
3. Call apex function where this lead record is given as input and perform a custom validation
4. In case of validation error, return back to the initial screen **but the values need to be as filled in by the user**.
   [image]

***Problem:***
When navigating back to the initial screen, all the values of picklist fields are returned to the --none-- choice, however i want to keep the previous one selected by the user.

1. I don't want to have all the choices separately, since they may change often, so i want to get all the  picklist values dynamically.
2. I want this flow to be able to be functional on partner communities.

How could i resolve this issue? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Create a new Text flow variable and assign it as Default Value for picklist field. You can assign 'None' as default value to new variable.

Comment: Hi Ashish and thanks for your response. But when it redirects due to validation, i want the default value to be the selected one (not none). And all the available options to be none, as well as all the values of the respective picklist field. How could this be achieved?